# How to create image preview?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, lightbox2

I am trying to implement lighbox2 to my website, however, it does not work as presented. On the official website, it shows the preview but I cannot get it to show it. It just says "Image 1" as a text and then when I click, the image is properly displayed. Should I enable anything? I followed the official tutorial.

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk" class="h-full">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        <link href="lightbox2-2.11.4/dist/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Maškrtníček</title>
   
        <div class="text-2xl text-center w-full bg-orange-200 py-6" id="fotky">
            <h2 class="text-2xl">Fotky</h2>
            <a href="pictures/proxy-image.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
        </div>
       
    </body>
</html>`

Thank you.
```

When I use `<img class="example-image" src="pictures/proxy-image.png" alt="Golden Gate Bridge with San Francisco in distance">` instead, loads something but the image is not clickable.

Comment: how have you configured lightbox? I'm guessing it requires some more than just including it on the page

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The image preview works just fine. The issue is that I get text instead of small image preview on the website. I have not done any special lightbox2 modification apart from the official tutorial and editing the image folder.

Comment: Welcome! You still need to include the `img` inside of your `<a>` to display the thumbnail. The `<a>` only creates the link lightbox needs to display the larger image using the `data-lightbox` attribute.  Like this: `<a href="pictures/proxy-image.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img class="example-image" src="pictures/proxy-image.png" alt="Golden Gate Bridge with San Francisco in distance"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

href="pictures/proxy-image.png"
and
src="pictures/proxy-image.png"
Are linking to the same file
They should link to 2 seperate files
The href=" is the full size image
and
src="  is a thumbnail image

JonofLeeds

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).